# ADO.NET to update table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework

I am using ADO.NET and trying to update a column value in a table in a SQL Server 2008 database. However the value is not updating. Even though it's update when I debug it in C# code. Here is my code:

```
using (ADONETClass context = new ADONETClass())
{
   List<Invoices> list = context.Invoices.ToList<Invoices>();
   foreach (Invoices b in list)
   {
      b.status = 0;
   }
}
```

Now I debugged the code and saw that `context.Invoices.ToList<Invoices>()[0].status` is indeed set to zero. But when the program finished running, I open the SQL Server Management Studio and status value there was still 0. Not sure what is going on? Am I missing something?

Thanks

Varun

Comment: If you're using Entity framework, why did you mark this as ado.net? Classic ado.net looks quite different and you need a different solution. So what is it? Ado.net or EF?

Comment: Oh ok, didn't knew that ! I wrote my first program today. My C# project contains a file Model1.edmx which is ADO .NET Entity Data Model. So I thought this is ADO .NET

Comment: EF is ORM on top of ado.net. With ado.net itself you would need to write actual SQL queries, manage connections etc. With EF (and similar ORMs), you focus on the logic part - getting results, managing relations, ..., while lower-level stuff is hidden from you most of the time.

Comment: Oh thanks Walter ! Actually haven't got any knowledge of that yet ! But it's good to know now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you calling context.SaveChanges()?

Comment: No Sorry, I am not calling anything like that. I will try now and see what happens !

Comment: Thanks. That worked and solved my problem. By the way, where can I get I this type of information from? Books / MSDN etc.? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @VVV, precisely + video tutorials etc... But most of all - google. Endless source of goodies for every programmer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Entity Framework?
I think you're missing a call to context.SaveChanges
In EntityFramework the changes are all just in memory and not written to database until you call SaveChanges